# Why are my accelerometer readings so slow?

Tags: iphone, performance, accelerometer

Somewhere in the documentation they mentioned 400 Hz. Nice figure, but I end up getting something less than 100. Even on the latest, coolest, most awesome iPhone 4. And I'm not doing anything except incrementing a counter (ivar) and assigning the value to a label. Can't imagine this is the bottleneck.

I set the frequency to the maximum possible (very small number, like 1.0/10000). It is supposed to be capped to the max whatever the hardware supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust that frequency - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724374/accelerometer-samplerate/1724461#1724461).

Comment: I set that to a very high frequency which is supposed to be capped down to the max automatically. Unfortunately this has no effect.